# Is there a standart practice when dealing with a list of error tuples?

Tags: elixir

In my application I want to apply functions on a list of values.

Because the functions operate with a web API or a database I have to check for errors. One was would be to return a tuple of `{:ok, result}` or `{:error, reason}`, which would result in a list of said tuples.

I could check this list with a function such as the one below. However, this seems very clunky and I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution. Maybe the use of exceptions?

```
def check_errors(lst) do
    if Enum.any?(lst, fn {s, _} -> s == :error end) do
        errors = Enum.filter(lst, fn {s, b} -> s == :error end)
                    |> Enum.map(fn {s, b} -> b end)
        IO.puts("Found Errors: ")
        IO.inspect(errors)
        System.halt(0)
    else
        lst
    end
end
```

Comment: you should never handle errors inside of functions, just return `{:error, :reason}`. Exceptions in elixir are used as a mechanism for sending error to parent process and should be used only when there is a application breaking error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many different ways but in the described scenario, [`Enum.split_with/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#split_with/2) is your friend.

```rb
[{:ok, 1}, {:error, 2}, {:ok, 3}]
|> Enum.split_with(fn {:error, _} -> true; _ -> false end)
|> case do
  {[], oks} ->
     oks
  {errors, _} ->
     errors
     |> Enum.map(&elem(&1, 1))
     |> IO.inspect(label: "Found errors")
end
```

Also, the swiss knife [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) might be used as in all the other cases when one needs to fold a list.

```rb
[{:ok, 1}, {:error, 2}, {:ok, 3}]
|> Enum.reverse() # needed to prepend below
                  # preserving the original order
|> Enum.reduce(%{errors: [], oks: []}, fn
  {:error, error}, acc ->
    %{acc | errors: [error | acc.errors]}
  {:ok, ok}, acc ->
    %{acc | oks: [ok | acc.oks]}
end) 
#⇒ %{errors: [2], oks: [1, 3]}
```

---

*As @Daniel absolutely correct said in comments,* “Exceptions in elixir are used as a mechanism for sending error to parent process and should be used only when there is a application breaking error.”